# Getting all Android device images

Tags: android, android-cursor

I need to get all images of my android device based on date they are added, so I tried below code:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};
mImageCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
mImageCursor.moveToFirst();
```

It works well on most devices but the problem appears on Nexus 5, I heard it crashes. Unfortunately I Do not have Nexus 5 to check the log but I think it is probably because Nexus 5 has no sd card, Am I right? What is the solution?

Comment: Rather than worry about this, you need to first focus on being able to collect stack traces. **Never** ship an app without the ability to find out what is going wrong. While the Nexus 5 does not have an SD card slot, your code has nothing to do with an SD card slot, and `MediaStore` works just fine on a Nexus 5 in general.

Comment: that nexus runs android 6, can this be the cause?

Comment: Starting with Android 5.0, you need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for some `MediaStore` operations, and starting with Android 6.0, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, that requires that you work with the runtime permission system. If your `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, and the Android 6.0 user manually revoked your `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I'm not quite sure what the behavior is with respect to `MediaStore`, as I haven't tried that particular scenario yet.

Comment: yes your right, it because of permissions in android 6, you can answer the question so I choose it if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Android 5.0, you need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for some `MediaStore` operations, and starting with Android 6.0, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, that requires that you work with the runtime permission system. Specifically, you would need to use `requestPermissions()` to prompt the user to grant you the ability to read from external storage, as that is considered to be a `dangerous` permission.

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, and the Android 6.0 user manually revoked your `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission via the Settings app, I'm not quite sure what the behavior is with respect to `MediaStore`, as I haven't tried that particular scenario yet.